# Exporting and requiring Express application issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

Taking the following basic [**Express: 'Hello World'**](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) example as my starting point:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I'm trying to organize the code in different `.js` files to separate configuration and routing.

This way I would have `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

and `/routes/api.js` (having `api.js` inside a child directory called `routes`):

```
var app = require('../app.js');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

but `exports = module.exports = app;` and `var app = require('../app.js');` are not working: I get the message `Cannot GET /` all the time when calling the API method.

Comment: you should do this the other way around - have app.js and in app.js require routes/api.js

Comment: @Tamas if you could please answer the question giving out an example of how it should be done, I would appreciate it and chose it as correct.

Comment: Nir got you sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should make `app.js` your 'main' file, and the routes should be inclulded in it.

your route file should look somthing like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and to your `app.js` add:

```
var api = require("./routes/api.js");
...
//all your code for creating app 
...
app.use('/', api);
```